An 18-Letter Challenge-B: three 6-letter words, with limitations
Using the YAWL wordlist https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl/archive/master.zip:

Locate three 6-letter words comprised of 18 unique letters,
Using C and V,
Not using KRANTZ / PLONGD / PRANCK,
Using a maximum of 3 vowels total (AEIOUY).

(I tried to make this work with CRWTHS, but couldn't find a single other 1-vowel word from the remaining letters. Should've known it wouldn't work when "Dmplz vng fkQ BXJ" with single vowels added to an anagrammer returned 0 results each time.)
Created as a separate post per bobble's suggestion.
PS: Should this wind up impossible, try this alternate and equally impossible challenge:
An 18-Letter Challenge-A: three 6-letter words, with limitations

Is Y a vowel for this puzzle (regardless of its use in a word)?

Yes, since these kinds of puzzles tend towards such usages ("Tyings" etc). Edited the OP to reflect; thanks!

Via integer linear programming, the maximum number of unique letters is

 17: {'FRUMPS','IDLING','KVETCH'}

There are $520$ such solutions.

 {'BANDAR','GLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BANJAX','GLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'PLUCKS','VENGED','WARMTH'}
 {'CRWTHS','JAMBUL','VIKING'}
 {'DIVING','FLETCH','SKRUMP'}
 {'FARAND','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'BLINTZ','CHAMPS','KERVED'}
 {'FLOCKS','VENGED','WARMTH'}
 {'CHINTZ','GLUMPS','VAWARD'}
 {'GRAMPS','KVETCH','ONFLOW'}
 {'APLOMB','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'FLUMPS','KVETCH','WIRING'}
 {'FRUMPS','KVETCH','WILING'}
 {'DIVING','FLOCKS','WARMTH'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','LAWMAN'}
 {'BRONDS','JUGFUL','KVETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLAMBE','JIVING'}
 {'FLUMPS','KNITCH','VERGED'}
 {'FIBRIN','GLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'APLOMB','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'CHINTZ','GLUMPS','KERVED'}
 {'BANDAR','FLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'FIXING','KVETCH','PROWLS'}
 {'BANJAX','CRWTHS','FULVID'}
 {'JIBING','KVETCH','PROWLS'}
 {'APLOMB','CRWTHS','DIVING'}
 {'CHINTZ','PLUMBS','VAWARD'}
 {'CRWTHS','DUMBLY','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIMPLY','VENGED'}
 {'BLINTZ','CHOMPS','VAWARD'}
 {'FLIMPS','GURJUN','KVETCH'}
 {'BLINDS','KVETCH','POGROM'}
 {'BAGMAN','FJORDS','KVETCH'}
 {'KVETCH','MZUNGU','SPRAWL'}
 {'GLUMPS','THWACK','VENDER'}
 {'DRAWLS','IMPING','KVETCH'}
 {'BLOTCH','FRUMPS','VENGED'}
 {'BIKING','CRWTHS','VAMPED'}
 {'FLIMPS','GODOWN','KVETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','PABLUM','VIKING'}
 {'FJORDS','PHLEGM','VACANT'}
 {'DWARFS','KVETCH','LIMING'}
 {'CRWTHS','MUZJIK','VANDAL'}
 {'CRWTHS','DIVING','JAMBOK'}
 {'BLINTZ','CHUMPS','VAWARD'}
 {'BANJAX','FLIMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BLOTCH','FREMDS','JIVING'}
 {'FLUMPS','THWACK','VENDER'}
 {'FLIMPS','THWACK','VENDER'}
 {'FLUMPS','KNITCH','VAWARD'}
 {'BLOTCH','FRUMPS','WIVING'}
 {'BLOTCH','FREMDS','VIKING'}
 {'BLOCKS','VENGED','WARMTH'}
 {'CRWTHS','GLOVED','JAMPAN'}
 {'CRWTHS','KEMPED','VOLING'}
 {'CRWTHS','KEMPED','LOVING'}
 {'FRATCH','PLUMBS','VIKING'}
 {'DIVING','FRATCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'FRATCH','PLUMBS','VENGED'}
 {'FLITCH','SKRUMP','VENGED'}
 {'BLINTZ','VERGED','WHACKS'}
 {'CRWTHS','KEMBED','VOLING'}
 {'FRUMPS','KLATCH','VENGED'}
 {'CRWTHS','KEMBED','LOVING'}
 {'DRACHM','JIVING','SPELTZ'}
 {'FRUMPS','IDLING','KVETCH'}
 {'BLINTZ','PREVED','WHACKS'}
 {'FRUMPS','JANDAL','KVETCH'}
 {'BANJAX','FLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'FLAWNS','KVETCH','POGROM'}
 {'BRONDS','KVETCH','MUGFUL'}
 {'FLUMPS','JIVING','WRETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','JUMBLY','VENGED'}
 {'CRWTHS','JYMOLD','VIKING'}
 {'FLUMPS','THWACK','VIRGIN'}
 {'FLUMPS','RIVING','THWACK'}
 {'DIVING','FRUMPS','THWACK'}
 {'DIVING','FLUMPS','THWACK'}
 {'FRUMPS','LIVING','THWACK'}
 {'FLUMPS','THWACK','VIRING'}
 {'FLUMPS','THWACK','VENGED'}
 {'FJELDS','THWACK','VIRGIN'}
 {'FRUMPS','THWACK','VENGED'}
 {'FJELDS','RIVING','THWACK'}
 {'FREMDS','LIVING','THWACK'}
 {'FLINGS','PERVED','THWACK'}
 {'PLUMBS','THWACK','VIRGIN'}
 {'FLIMPS','THWACK','VENGED'}
 {'FJELDS','THWACK','VIRING'}
 {'FLUMPS','NERVED','THWACK'}
 {'PLUMBS','RIVING','THWACK'}
 {'FLUMPS','THWACK','VENGER'}
 {'PLUMBS','THWACK','VIRING'}
 {'PLUMBS','THWACK','VERGED'}
 {'FLIMPS','THWACK','VENGER'}
 {'DIVING','KLEPHT','SCRAWM'}
 {'DIVING','PLUMBS','THWACK'}
 {'FLIMPS','NERVED','THWACK'}
 {'DIVING','FLUMPS','WRETCH'}
 {'FLUMPS','THWACK','VERGED'}
 {'PLUMBS','THWACK','VENGED'}
 {'FLIMPS','THWACK','VERGED'}
 {'BLIMPS','THWACK','VERGED'}
 {'NERVED','PLUMBS','THWACK'}
 {'KLEPHT','SCRAMB','WIVING'}
 {'FRUMPS','KLATCH','WIVING'}
 {'PLUMBS','THWACK','VENGER'}
 {'BLIMPS','THWACK','VENGED'}
 {'DIVING','PLUMBS','WRETCH'}
 {'PLUMBS','THWACK','VENDER'}
 {'BLIMPS','NERVED','THWACK'}
 {'FRATCH','PLUMBS','WIVING'}
 {'GLUMPS','NERVED','THWACK'}
 {'BLIMPS','THWACK','VENGER'}
 {'FLETCH','SKRUMP','WIVING'}
 {'CRUMBS','KLEPHT','WIVING'}
 {'BLIMPS','THWACK','VENDER'}
 {'CRWTHS','DIVING','FUMBLE'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLAVIN','KEMBED'}
 {'CRWTHS','FULVID','JAMPAN'}
 {'CRWTHS','JUGFUL','KNIVED'}
 {'CRWTHS','KNIVED','MUGFUL'}
 {'CRWTHS','DIVING','JAMBUL'}
 {'CRWTHS','DIVING','FLAMBE'}
 {'BEFLUM','CRWTHS','DIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','DIVING','JUMBAL'}
 {'CRWTHS','DIVING','JUMBLE'}
 {'CRWTHS','DIVING','PABLUM'}
 {'CRWTHS','JAMBUL','VENGED'}
 {'CLUMPS','KNIGHT','VAWARD'}
 {'CRWTHS','KEMBED','PAVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JUMBAL','VENGED'}
 {'CRWTHS','KEMBED','LAVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','DEFLEX','PAVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JUMPED','LIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','PABLUM','VENGED'}
 {'BUNKUM','CRWTHS','GEVALD'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLAVIN','KEMPED'}
 {'GLUMPS','KNITCH','VAWARD'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLEXED','PAVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','LAMBDA','VEXING'}
 {'CRWTHS','LAMPAD','VEXING'}
 {'BUMPED','CRWTHS','LIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','KEMPED','LAVING'}
 {'KNITCH','PLUMBS','VAWARD'}
 {'BALMED','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'AMBLED','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'BAGMAN','CRWTHS','FULVID'}
 {'CRWTHS','FABLED','VIKING'}
 {'BEDLAM','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JAMBED','LIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FIXING','VAMPED'}
 {'CRWTHS','FIKING','VAMPED'}
 {'BLAMED','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','LAMBED','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','DJEBEL','PAVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','KEMPLE','VADING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIBING','VAMPED'}
 {'CRWTHS','JUGFUL','VAMPED'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLUXED','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FUMBLE','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','PALMED','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLAMED','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','PLUMED','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','DUPLEX','VIKING'}
 {'BEFLUM','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'FLUMPS','VIKING','WRETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','JUMBLE','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','MALFED','VIKING'}
 {'BUMPED','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLAMBE','VIKING'}
 {'BLUMED','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JAMBED','VIKING'}
 {'BELDAM','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLUMED','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLAVIN','MUDBUG'}
 {'CRWTHS','FILING','VAMPED'}
 {'CRWTHS','DUMPLE','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','LIKING','VAMPED'}
 {'CRWTHS','LUMPED','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','KELVIN','MUDBUG'}
 {'FLINGS','PREVED','THWACK'}
 {'CRWTHS','JUMBAL','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JUMPED','VIKING'}
 {'KVETCH','MAZARD','PLONGS'}
 {'KVETCH','MZUNGU','PROWLS'}
 {'KVETCH','MUGFUL','PRAWNS'}
 {'DWARFS','KLEPHT','VICING'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','MZUNGU'}
 {'FLONGS','PERVED','THWACK'}
 {'FJORDS','LIVING','THWACK'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','ZAMANG'}
 {'AFAWLD','GRUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'CLOMPS','KNIGHT','VAWARD'}
 {'FLONGS','PREVED','THWACK'}
 {'BRAWNS','KVETCH','MUGFUL'}
 {'BLINTZ','SHMOCK','VAWARD'}
 {'FLUMPS','GODOWN','KVETCH'}
 {'FRUMPS','GODOWN','KVETCH'}
 {'JUGFUL','KVETCH','POWNDS'}
 {'KVETCH','MUGFUL','POWNDS'}
 {'DROWND','FLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'FLAWNS','KVETCH','MIDRIB'}
 {'GRUMPS','KVETCH','ONFLOW'}
 {'BRAWNS','KVETCH','LIMPID'}
 {'KVETCH','MIXING','SPRAWL'}
 {'BRAWLS','KVETCH','MIXING'}
 {'DWALMS','KVETCH','RIPING'}
 {'KVETCH','LIMPID','WRANGS'}
 {'DWALMS','JIBING','KVETCH'}
 {'BRAWLS','IMPING','KVETCH'}
 {'KVETCH','LAMBDA','WRINGS'}
 {'KVETCH','PLUMBS','WIRING'}
 {'DWALMS','FIBRIN','KVETCH'}
 {'DWARFS','IMPING','KVETCH'}
 {'DRAWLS','KVETCH','MIXING'}
 {'DROWND','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'GODOWN','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'DROWND','GLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'DWALMS','FIRING','KVETCH'}
 {'DWALMS','FIXING','KVETCH'}
 {'KVETCH','MUDBUG','PROWLS'}
 {'BULGUR','KVETCH','POWNDS'}
 {'KVETCH','MUGFUL','ROWNDS'}
 {'JUGFUL','KVETCH','ROWNDS'}
 {'DROWNS','JUGFUL','KVETCH'}
 {'DROWNS','KVETCH','MUGFUL'}
 {'FROWNS','KVETCH','MUDBUG'}
 {'BROWNS','JUGFUL','KVETCH'}
 {'BROWNS','KVETCH','MUGFUL'}
 {'BLOTCH','FREMDS','WIVING'}
 {'BLOTCH','DIVING','FRUMPS'}
 {'KVETCH','MUDBUG','PRAWNS'}
 {'FLAWNS','GOMBRO','KVETCH'}
 {'BLOTCH','FRUMPS','VIKING'}
 {'KVETCH','MUDBUG','SPRAWL'}
 {'FLAWNS','KVETCH','MUDBUG'}
 {'FROWNS','KVETCH','LAMBDA'}
 {'BLOTCH','DIVING','SKRUMP'}
 {'KVETCH','PLUMBS','WIFING'}
 {'BLOTCH','SKRUMP','VENGED'}
 {'KVETCH','SPRUNG','WADMAL'}
 {'BAGMAN','KVETCH','WORLDS'}
 {'BLINTZ','PERVED','SHMOCK'}
 {'CROMBS','KLEPHT','WIVING'}
 {'CROMBS','DIVING','KLEPHT'}
 {'BRINGS','KVETCH','PODZOL'}
 {'BLOTCH','DWARFS','VIKING'}
 {'BLOTCH','SKRIMP','VENGED'}
 {'CRWTHS','PEGBOX','VANDAL'}
 {'BLINTZ','CHOMPS','VERGED'}
 {'BLINTZ','SHMOCK','VERGED'}
 {'BADMAN','GROWLS','KVETCH'}
 {'JIBING','KVETCH','WORLDS'}
 {'KVETCH','LAMBDA','WRONGS'}
 {'DWARFS','KVETCH','OBLONG'}
 {'KVETCH','MZUNGU','WORLDS'}
 {'BLINTZ','PREVED','SHMOCK'}
 {'KVETCH','WORLDS','ZAMANG'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','WILING'}
 {'DWANGS','FORMOL','KVETCH'}
 {'KVETCH','SPRING','WADMAL'}
 {'KVETCH','LAMBDA','SPRING'}
 {'KVETCH','PODZOL','WRANGS'}
 {'CRWTHS','FULVID','ZAMANG'}
 {'AFAWLD','KVETCH','SPRING'}
 {'KVETCH','POWNDS','RAMBLA'}
 {'CRWTHS','MAGLEV','PONDOK'}
 {'BIDING','KVETCH','PROWLS'}
 {'KVETCH','SPRONG','WADMAL'}
 {'KVETCH','PRONGS','WADMAL'}
 {'JAMPAN','KVETCH','WORLDS'}
 {'GRAMPA','KVETCH','LOWNDS'}
 {'DROWND','FLIMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BLIMPS','DROWND','KVETCH'}
 {'BROWNS','KVETCH','LIMPID'}
 {'BUNKUM','CRWTHS','GLOVED'}
 {'CRWTHS','KELPED','MOVING'}
 {'BLINTZ','PERVED','WHACKS'}
 {'FJELDS','VICING','WARMTH'}
 {'FLICKS','VENGED','WARMTH'}
 {'BLIMPS','GODOWN','KVETCH'}
 {'DIVING','FLECKS','WARMTH'}
 {'DIVING','PLUCKS','WARMTH'}
 {'IMPING','KVETCH','WORLDS'}
 {'KVETCH','LIMPID','WRONGS'}
 {'FIBRIL','KVETCH','POWNDS'}
 {'CHINTZ','FLUMPS','VAWARD'}
 {'FRICHT','PLUMBS','VENGED'}
 {'BEFELD','CRWTHS','MOVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','KOBOLD','MEVING'}
 {'BLIMPS','FRATCH','VENGED'}
 {'DRACHM','SPELTZ','WIVING'}
 {'DIVING','FRUMPS','KLATCH'}
 {'BLINTZ','SHMUCK','VAWARD'}
 {'CRWTHS','OBLONG','VAMPED'}
 {'CRWTHS','MOBLED','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JAMBOK','LIVING'}
 {'BLOCKS','GRUMPH','VENTED'}
 {'KVETCH','PODZOL','WRINGS'}
 {'CRWTHS','JAMBOK','VENGED'}
 {'APLOMB','CRWTHS','VENGED'}
 {'BLINTZ','PERVED','SHMUCK'}
 {'BLINTZ','PREVED','SHMUCK'}
 {'ARGAND','BLIMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BRINGS','KVETCH','LAMPAD'}
 {'BLINDS','GRAMPA','KVETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','KOBOLD','PAVING'}
 {'BLIMPS','GARJAN','KVETCH'}
 {'KVETCH','OXFORD','PLUMBS'}
 {'CRWTHS','DJEBEL','MOVING'}
 {'BLINTZ','CHAMPS','VERGED'}
 {'BLIMPS','FARAND','KVETCH'}
 {'BOXFUL','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'BOXFUL','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'CRUMBS','DIVING','KLEPHT'}
 {'BANDAR','FLIMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BOXFUL','CRWTHS','DIVING'}
 {'AFAWLD','BRINGS','KVETCH'}
 {'BRAWNS','JUGFUL','KVETCH'}
 {'BOXFUL','CRWTHS','VENGED'}
 {'BRANDS','JUGFUL','KVETCH'}
 {'FLUMPS','GARJAN','KVETCH'}
 {'ARGAND','FLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'FARAND','GLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'DRAWLS','JIBING','KVETCH'}
 {'AFAWLD','KVETCH','SPRUNG'}
 {'JUGFUL','KVETCH','PRAWNS'}
 {'DWANGS','KVETCH','UPFURL'}
 {'BRAWLS','FIXING','KVETCH'}
 {'FRUMPS','JIBING','KVETCH'}
 {'FLUMPS','JIBING','KVETCH'}
 {'FIRING','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'DWANGS','KVETCH','RIFLIP'}
 {'BIDING','FLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BIDING','FRUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BRAWLS','KVETCH','PIDGIN'}
 {'KVETCH','PLUMBS','RIDING'}
 {'CHINTZ','PLUMBS','VERGED'}
 {'DRACHM','SPELTZ','VIKING'}
 {'GLUMPS','KVETCH','OXFORD'}
 {'BANJAX','GRUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BANJAX','CRWTHS','GLOVED'}
 {'GARJAN','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','MIXING'}
 {'ARGAND','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'DIVING','KLEPHT','SCRAMB'}
 {'KVETCH','LAMBDA','SPRUNG'}
 {'KNITCH','PLUMBS','VERGED'}
 {'FJORDS','KLEPHT','VICING'}
 {'BANJAX','FRUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLYPED','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','VENGED','ZAMBUK'}
 {'FROWNS','KVETCH','LAMPAD'}
 {'CRWTHS','MEVING','PODZOL'}
 {'JIVING','PLUMBS','THWACK'}
 {'JIVING','PLUMBS','WRETCH'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','PILING'}
 {'DWARFS','KVETCH','MONGOL'}
 {'AFAWLD','KVETCH','SPRONG'}
 {'DRONGO','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'AFAWLD','KVETCH','PRONGS'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','NAPALM'}
 {'DOBLON','GRUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','DEFLEX','MOVING'}
 {'DRONGO','FLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'FRUMPS','KVETCH','OBLONG'}
 {'KVETCH','LAMPAD','WRONGS'}
 {'JIBING','KVETCH','SPRAWL'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','UNPLUG'}
 {'FLIMPS','GARJAN','KVETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLEXED','MOVING'}
 {'ARGAND','FLIMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BRANDS','KVETCH','MUGFUL'}
 {'BIDING','KVETCH','SPRAWL'}
 {'DOBLON','FRUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BANJAX','KVETCH','PROWLS'}
 {'BANJAX','KVETCH','WORLDS'}
 {'BANJAX','GROWLS','KVETCH'}
 {'BRAWNS','KVETCH','PODZOL'}
 {'FJORDS','IMPING','KVETCH'}
 {'FLONGS','KVETCH','MIDRIB'}
 {'BAGMAN','KVETCH','PROWLS'}
 {'BROWNS','KVETCH','LAMPAD'}
 {'GROWLS','JAMPAN','KVETCH'}
 {'BADMAN','KVETCH','PROWLS'}
 {'FIXING','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'KVETCH','LAMBDA','SPRONG'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','LIMING'}
 {'KVETCH','LAMBDA','PRONGS'}
 {'CRWTHS','JUMBLY','VIKING'}
 {'BLANDS','KVETCH','POGROM'}
 {'CRWTHS','DUMBLY','VIKING'}
 {'DOBLON','GRAMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','KOBOLD','VEXING'}
 {'BLONDS','GRAMPA','KVETCH'}
 {'KVETCH','PROWLS','ZAMANG'}
 {'FIXING','KVETCH','SPRAWL'}
 {'CRWTHS','DIVING','ZAMBUK'}
 {'CRWTHS','LIVING','ZAMBUK'}
 {'DWARFS','KVETCH','PILING'}
 {'BLIMPS','DRONGO','KVETCH'}
 {'KVETCH','MIDRIB','PLONGS'}
 {'DRONGO','FLIMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'FRATCH','JIVING','PLUMBS'}
 {'KVETCH','MAZARD','PLINGS'}
 {'FLINGS','KVETCH','MAZARD'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','WIPING'}
 {'DRAWLS','FIXING','KVETCH'}
 {'KVETCH','MIXING','PROWLS'}
 {'DWARFS','JIBING','KVETCH'}
 {'KVETCH','MIXING','WORLDS'}
 {'BLIMPS','KVETCH','OXFORD'}
 {'DWANGS','FIBRIL','KVETCH'}
 {'CRWTHS','MEDFLY','VIKING'}
 {'BLAZED','CRWTHS','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','MEDFLY'}
 {'BLAZED','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'BLINTZ','SHMUCK','VERGED'}
 {'CRWTHS','DAMPLY','VIKING'}
 {'CHINTZ','FLUMPS','VERGED'}
 {'CRWTHS','PODZOL','VEXING'}
 {'CHINTZ','FLUMPS','KERVED'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','PABLUM'}
 {'FIXING','KVETCH','WORLDS'}
 {'CRWTHS','DAMPLY','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLYPED','JIVING'}
 {'BLINTZ','CHUMPS','KERVED'}
 {'KVETCH','OXFORD','PLINGS'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','PLUMED'}
 {'CRWTHS','DIVING','JUMBLY'}
 {'BRAWLS','KVETCH','MZUNGU'}
 {'DWARFS','KVETCH','MZUNGU'}
 {'AMBLED','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','DUMPLE','JIVING'}
 {'BLUMED','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'BUMPED','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','LUMPED'}
 {'CRWTHS','DUPLEX','JIVING'}
 {'BALMED','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'FLECKS','JIVING','WARMTH'}
 {'BEDLAM','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'BLAMED','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','LAMBED'}
 {'BELDAM','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','MALFED'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLUXED','JIVING'}
 {'CRUMBS','JIVING','KLEPHT'}
 {'FLETCH','JIVING','SKRUMP'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLUKED','JIVING'}
 {'BULKED','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLUMED','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FUMBLE','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','PALMED'}
 {'FLUMPS','JIVING','THWACK'}
 {'BEFLUM','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'JIVING','KLEPHT','SCRAWM'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','LAMPED'}
 {'FLICKS','GRUMPH','VENTED'}
 {'FREMDS','JIVING','KLATCH'}
 {'JIVING','KLEPHT','SCRAMB'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLAKED','JIVING'}
 {'BALKED','CRWTHS','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FLAMED','JIVING'}
 {'CRWTHS','FABLED','JIVING'}
 {'FRUMPS','JIVING','KLATCH'}
 {'FRUMPS','JIVING','THWACK'}
 {'JIVING','PLUCKS','WARMTH'}
 {'FREMDS','JIVING','THWACK'}
 {'FLACKS','GRUMPH','VENTED'}
 {'BLACKS','GRUMPH','VENTED'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','ZAMBUK'}
 {'BLOCKS','JIVING','WARMTH'}
 {'FLOCKS','JIVING','WARMTH'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','POLKED'}
 {'GRUMPH','INWICK','VELDTS'}
 {'BLOTCH','JIVING','SKRUMP'}
 {'FJELDS','GRUMPH','VACANT'}
 {'CRWTHS','FOLDUP','JIVING'}
 {'BLOTCH','FRUMPS','JIVING'}
 {'CROMBS','JIVING','KLEPHT'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','MOBLED'}
 {'CRWTHS','DOGFOX','KELVIN'}
 {'BLOTCH','DWARFS','JIVING'}
 {'CROWDS','JIVING','KLEPHT'}
 {'BLIMPS','DOGFOX','KVETCH'}
 {'DOGFOX','KVETCH','PRAWNS'}
 {'BRAWNS','DOGFOX','KVETCH'}
 {'DOGFOX','KVETCH','SPRAWL'}
 {'CRWTHS','JIVING','UPFOLD'}
 {'BRAWLS','DOGFOX','KVETCH'}
 {'DOGFOX','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'FRIGID','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}
 {'CRWTHS','MUZJIK','VENGED'}
 {'FROWNS','KVETCH','LIMPID'}
 {'BLINTZ','CHUMPS','VERGED'}
 {'CRWTHS','FOLDUP','VIKING'}
 {'CRWTHS','UPFOLD','VIKING'}
 {'FJORDS','KVETCH','MANGAL'}
 {'CHINTZ','KERVED','PLUMBS'}
 {'DRAWLS','KVETCH','MZUNGU'}
 {'BEFELD','CRWTHS','PAVING'}
 {'FLONGS','KVETCH','MAZARD'}
 {'DWALMS','GURJUN','KVETCH'}
 {'BLOTCH','SKRUMP','WIVING'}
 {'BRINGS','KVETCH','WADMAL'}
 {'BLOCKS','DIVING','WARMTH'}
 {'FLUMPS','KVETCH','RIDING'}
 {'DWARFS','KVETCH','UNPLUG'}
 {'BLINTZ','CHOMPS','KERVED'}
 {'CRWTHS','DOVING','KEMPLE'}
 {'BLIMPS','GURJUN','KVETCH'}
 {'FLOCKS','GRUMPH','VENTED'}
 {'PLUMBS','VIKING','WRETCH'}
 {'FREMDS','KLATCH','WIVING'}
 {'GRUMPS','JANDAL','KVETCH'}
 {'DWARFS','KVETCH','MIXING'}
 {'CRWTHS','LAMPED','VIKING'}
 {'FJORDS','KLATCH','WIVING'}
 {'KVETCH','LAMPAD','WRINGS'}

If you disallow the repeated letter to be a vowel, there are

 5 such solutions:


 {'DROWND','FLIMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'DROWND','FLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'BLIMPS','DROWND','KVETCH'}
 {'DROWND','GLUMPS','KVETCH'}
 {'DROWND','KVETCH','PLUMBS'}


What are the chances of you posting the raw text of 520 solutions in an edit? If so, I will check your reply off and call the question answered.

There are a lot of duplicate vowels in these sets. Am I missing something about the requirement that the letters be unique? My interpretation was 3 vowels total.

Oh I see, this is because 18 unique isn't possible...
